# client credentials grant type oauth2 token

Tags: java, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

My problem is that:

I have an e-commerce site that can send http requests to my server S1.
The e-commerce site must first have a token provided by  my authentication server.

How can I do to get an oauth2 token from my authentication server before sending my requests to S1.

I am using Springboot and oauth2.

Thanks.

Comment: This may helpful, refer implicit example [link](https://github.com/Baeldung/spring-security-oauth)

Comment: thanks @Ishara. Do you have another example with client credentials granted type